# Reimburse of Social Taxes like Insurance , Pensions in Germany

Tags: germany, salary, pension

I am a software engineer. If I worked for 5 years in Germany and have to move back to my home country, then can I get back the Social taxes (like pension, health insurance, etc...) deducted form my salary in Germany?

Comment: You changed the question, now my comments is not correct, so i delete it.

Comment: What makes you think you could get health insurance back?

Comment: if you worked for 5 years in Germany, you may apply for rent/pension from abroad when you will turn 67, so even if you won't get it back, it will not be wasted.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The **health insurance** covered any medical costs during the time you were insured.

The **pension** contributions for the 5 years that you have worked will be stored and rated in the form of points, for each year, from 0 to 100

- 50 being for an **average** wage for that year of all employees in Germany
- 100 for the highest amount possible (2019: € 54.450,00)

These will be stored in your **pension account**

- the **Versicherungsnummer** is the account number

**Note**:
If you have **studied** in Germany, these times may count (for the pension) as if you have worked, so points are possible for these times. They are, however, not added automatically.

At anytime you can apply for a **Kontoklärung** (Account Clairification)

- if you have studied and then started to work, one year after that start is a good time to do this

In the result (**Versichungsverlauf**) you should see the months when you were working (which should be compleate), the months of **study will be missing**

- submit proof of study **with dates**
- submit proof of work that may be missing

A part of a month (5th, 15th or 25th) is considered a **full** month.

These times will then be added to your account and a new result will be sent which should now be complete.

It is better to do this **now** than in 40 years time!

---

When you apply for a **pension** in another country, these times may also be taken into consideration - depending on existing treatys.

Before you leave Germany you should apply for a '[Kontoklärung](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Formulare/DE/_pdf/V0100.html;jsessionid=3804C66FD385482D749E57824AE12E50.delivery2-2-replication)' by filling out the pdf form.

- you can also fill out the form [electronically](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Formulare/DE/_pdf/V0100.html;jsessionid=3804C66FD385482D749E57824AE12E50.delivery2-2-replication)

  - **Versicherungsverlauf**

You will recieve a result showing all monthly **pension** payments for the time spent in Germany.

The final result (**Versichungsverlauf**) will be proof of what you paid in and can later claim.